# PHP undefined offset array error

Tags: php, arrays, offset

I made this array for an assignment, but I can't quite get it right. What I need for it to do is recognize a string from my array and print off if "I'm learning it". I think I'm close, but I keep getting undefined offset.

```
 $myArray = array ("C ", "Java", "C++ ", "Objective-C", "C#", "PHP","(Visual)
                   Basic", "Python", "JavaScript", "Perl", "Ruby",
                   "PL/SQL", "Delphi/Oject pascal","Visual Basic.Net",
                   "lisp", "Pascal", "Ada", "Transact-SQL", "Logo", "NXT-G");

for ($i = 0; $i<sizeof($myArray); $i++)
    echo $myArray[$i];

if($myArray[$i] == "C") {
    echo "I'm learning this too!";
}
else {
    echo "Your not learning anything";
}
```

Comment: Except if using a `for` loop is mandatory, you can do the same using the [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)  function without an explicit loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing brackets for `for loop`

```
    $myArray = array ("C ", "Java", "C++ ", "Objective-C", "C#", "PHP","(Visual)
                   Basic", "Python", "JavaScript", "Perl", "Ruby",
                  "PL/SQL", "Delphi/Oject pascal","Visual Basic.Net",
                 "lisp", "Pasca", "Ada", "Transact-SQL", "Logo", "NXT-G");

for ($i = 0; $i< sizeof($myArray); $i++)
{
  echo $myArray[$i]."<br>";
  if($myArray[$i] == "C") {
    echo "I'm learning this too!";
  }
  else {
    echo "Your not learning anything";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing enclosing braces on the for loop.

A for loop executes the single instruction after the for command a number of times. If you want to do multiple things, you need to combine them into a block with braces { }

```
for ($i = 0; $i<sizeof($myArray); $i++)
{
     echo $myArray[$i];
     if($myArray[$i] == "C") 
     {
         echo "I'm learning this too!";
     }
     else
     {
         echo "Your not learning anything";
     }
}
```

Try and closely adhere to a layout format for your blocks, otherwise it's harder to notice when your braces don't link up properly.